# Abnormal Behaviour string MPI_Send() and MPI_Recv()

Tags: c, mpi

My program is compiling and showing abnormal behaviour.

Used following commands for compiling

> mpicc one.c -o one
>
> mpiexec -n 2 ./one

I tried to debug it but show no compilation error.
I can't understand why my program is behaving abnormally

```
#include<mpi.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{

    char str[434];
    int n;
    int rank,size; MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    if(rank == 0)
    {//Sender process
        scanf("%s",&str);

        MPI_Ssend(&n,1,MPI_INT,1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Ssend(&str,n,MPI_CHAR,1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("Sending word %s in process 0\n",str);
    }
    else
    {//Receiver process
        MPI_Recv(&n,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        MPI_Recv(&str,n,MPI_CHAR,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        printf("Receiving word %s in process 1\n",str);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();


    return 0;
}
```

Input:

> haha

Actual result

> Sending word haha in process 0
>
> Receiving word haha in process 1

Exchange result

> Sending word haha in process 0
>
> Receiving word �������� in process 1

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. You are passing an address of a pointer to an array in e.g. `scanf` where you should simply pass pointer to the array `str`. The same problems occurs later in your code.

Comment: You never initialize `n`. And you should not use `&str` which is a pointer to the array (and of type `char (*)[434]`). Use either `&str[0]` or plain `str` (which decays to `&str[0]`). This use of `&str` is wrong everywhere you use it.

Answer (score 0):

As people have kindly pointed out in the comments to your post, you can't use `str` the way you were, because `scanf()` expects a `char *`, while you are passing it `char (*)[434]`, which are not the same.

You would see this error (or warning), if you compiled with the `"-Werror -Wformat"` flags.

After modifying your code to use an pointer and not a char array, it looks as below:

```
#include<mpi/mpi.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    const int size = 434;
    char* str_send = (char*) malloc(size * sizeof(char)); // = "haha";
    char* str_recv = (char*) malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    int n = size;
    int rank;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    if(rank == 0)
    {//Sender process
        scanf("%s", str_send);

        MPI_Ssend(&n,1,MPI_INT,1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Ssend(str_send,n,MPI_CHAR,1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("Sending word %s in process 0\n",str_send);
    }
    else
    {//Receiver process
        MPI_Recv(&n,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        MPI_Recv(str_recv,n,MPI_CHAR,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        printf("Receiving word %s in process 1\n",str_recv);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Which gives the output:

> junglefox@ubuntu:~/test_programs$ mpicc main.c
>
> junglefox@ubuntu:~/test_programs$ mpiexec -n 2 ./a.out
>
> haha
>
> Sending word haha in process 0
>
> Receiving word haha in process 1

Since, I feel you want to test the **MPI** library and not get bogged down into other intricacies, I would suggest using a fixed input and looking for the fixed output, instead of using `scanf`. As an example,

```
const char* str_send = "haha";
```

And then remove or comment out the scanf line.

```
// scanf("%s", str_send);
```

Comment: this is a bit of an overkill. simply use `str` instead of `&str` (and no need to change its type nor `malloc()` it) **and** initialize `n` (e.g. `n = strlen(str)+1`) on rank `0`. But if you want to hardcode `const char *str_send = "haha"`, you also need to hardcode `n=5`;

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, _"his is a bit of an overkill. simply use str instead of &str"_: maybe I am mistaken, but `scanf` needs the "address of `str`" and not `str` itself.

Comment: `scanf()` needs a pointer to a `char`. `char str[16]; scanf("%s", str);` is valid to me.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, yes, I agree. In that case the only thing to do would be setting `n`, as you have pointed out in your comment.